# Is it possible to use the Programmable Chat SDK without FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, twilio-programmable-chat

My situation is the following: I'm working on a custom version of Android (I'm not the author of it) which does not support google-services (or I haven't found yet a compatible version of them) so I can't use FCM for Push Notifications. Is FCM mandatory for using the Programmable Chat?

Note: At the moment I can use the Programmable Video SDK w/out FCM for invitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCM is not required to use Programmable Chat. Just ignore the registration functionality and it should work fine.